# OR operator in Java

Tags: java, operators

it's a "count and say" problem of an interview question and I'm trying the followed code to solve it:

```
public static String countAndSay(int n) {
    char[] c = new char[] { '1' };
    StringBuffer buffer = null;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int start = 0; 
        int len = c.length;
        for (int j = 1; j <= len; j++) {
            if (j == len || c[j] != c[start]) {
                buffer.append(j - start);
                buffer.append(c[start]);
                start = j;
            }
        }
        c = buffer.toString().toCharArray();
    }
    return new String(c);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(countAndSay(2));
}
```

here is the description of the problem:
The count-and-say sequence is the sequence of integers beginning as follows:
1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221,...

1 is read off as "one 1" or 11. 11 is read off as "two 1s" or 21. 21 is read off as "one 2, then one 1" or 1211. Given an integer n, generate the nth sequence.

It's a runnable code. but for the line `if (j == len || c[j] != c[start])`, if I change it to `if (c[j] != c[start] || j == len)`, there will be an error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I am confused why the different order of two conditions will have different result for an OR operator. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `||` is short circuiting. If `j == len` is evaluated to true, `c[j] != c[start]` is not evaluated because `true || whatever = true`.

Comment: so only if `j == len` is false, then `c[j] != c[start]` will be evaluated? thanks @ZouZou

Comment: Google lazy evaluation.

Comment: @Zihan Yes. For more informations, you can also consult the JLS: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.24.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (j == len || c[j] != c[start])
true---^              ^------Expression is NOT evaluated

 if (j == len || c[j] != c[start])
false---^             ^------Expression is evaluated
```

If the first expression is `true` then the jvm will not go to check the second expression in case of `OR` operator

Answer (score 0):

If the first expression evaluates to 'true', then the other expression is ignored when the expressions are separated by `OR` operator

Answer (score 0):

The Or operator is evaluated so that the options are evaluated in order from left to right, and when the first one is `true`, the whole statement is true. That means if you have `(valid-statement || invalid-statement)` and `valid-statement` is `true`, the `invalid-statement` never gets evaluated.